# How to auto reload value of localstorage in div tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have div tag like

some text

And

I have javascript

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = localstorage.getItem('myName');

How to auto reload and show localstorage value in div realtime even the localstorage is changed without refresh whole page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey just googled a bit to see how to monitor the changes in local storage found that , you can  create custom Event and event listener, and trigger the event when you are inserting the item to local storage by rewriting  the  setItem function.

i have found this [Listen for changes with localStorage on the same window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974084/listen-for-changes-with-localstorage-on-the-same-window) its worth a try.