# Listen for localStorage.setItem on same Window (FireFox & IE)

Tags: javascript, local-storage, addeventlistener, dom-events

I found this thread that answers partially:

[Listen for changes with localStorage on the same window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974084/listen-for-changes-with-localstorage-on-the-same-window)

Although it works in Chrome, I still wasn't able to figure out how to work on Firefox or IE.

Answer (score 0):

`Storage` interface emits `storage` event on global objects which it affects.

```
window.addEventListener("storage", function () {
    // your code
}, false);
```

this event will also be triggered when you use `setItem`.