# Trying to build an eventlistener for localStorage with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, event-listener, use-effect

I'm trying to implement an eventlistener that triggers an useEffect-function to render a shopping bag. At the moment the shopping bag only appears after reloading the page. This should happen instantly instead.
I've build a sandbox for my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-oskar-drsvy?file=/src/App.js.
When clicking the "Click it" button nothing appears but when reloading the page.

Here is also the code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [storageData, setStorageData] = useState(localStorage.getItem("alert"));

  useEffect(() => {
    setStorageData(localStorage.getItem("alert"));
  }, []);

  //insert eventlistener to dependency array of useEffect

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          localStorage.setItem("alert", "ShoppingBag");
        }}
      >
        click it
      </button>
      <div>{storageData}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Setting something in local storage will not trigger re-render .in your onClick handler you need to call the state updater function setStorageData('shoppingBag`) . local storage is to persist the value of your app even when you do refresh .

Comment: Maybe you need to update the `storageData` after button click. You have to add `setStorageData(localStorage.getItem("alert"));` in the button click callback.

Answer (score 2):

You need to kind of inverse how you are doing it - when you `storageData` changes, you should do `localStorage.setItem`, and then you do `setStorageData` and your `useEffect` will pick up the change and save it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-herschel-469i1

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [storageData, setStorageData] = useState(localStorage.getItem("alert"));

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("alert", storageData);
  }, [storageData]);

  //insert eventlistener to dependency array of useEffect

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setStorageData("ShoppingBag");
        }}
      >
        click it
      </button>
      <div>{storageData}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I set the localStorage in another component and I want to listen if the item is set or updated. If it changed I want to re-render this component.

Comment: Then you'd have to override `localStorage.setItem` to dispatch some sort of event that you listen to, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974084/listen-for-changes-with-localstorage-on-the-same-window, but the "React way" would be to hoist that state up to some common parent component, and pass the value and setter down as props to both components.