# How can I listen for localStorage change in 1 tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

How can I listen to `localStorage` changed in a single tab? I use addEventListener("storage"). But it only works if you open 2 or more tabs (I use React)

Answer (score 0):

First note that `single tab` does not meaning for `localStoage`. Your application may have multiple tab and all of tab share the `localStoage`.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974084/listen-for-changes-with-localstorage-on-the-same-window) you can override the `setItem` function and trigger an event:

```
var originalSetItem = localStorage.setItem; 
localStorage.setItem = function () {
    const event = new Event('itemInserted');
    originalSetItem.apply(this, arguments);
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

And the usage:

```
const localStorageSetHandler = function(e) {
  //do something
  console.log('localStorage.set("' + e.key + '", "' + e.value + '") was called');
};

document.addEventListener("itemInserted", localStorageSetHandler, false);

localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: I think that i didn't work for me

Comment: @JackDo I updated the answer. you can create event and then use `dispatchEvent`