# How to trigger a function automatically when the data in an array changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i just started React js and im trying to create a simple recipe web with API.

I am trying to create a page that will display the data of favorite recipes from an array in local storage using map() like below.

```
const FavRecipes = () => {

    const [recipeArray, setRecipeArray] = useState([]);

    const refreshData = () => {
        const existedFavRecipe = localStorage.getItem("FavRecipes");
        const data = existedFavRecipe !== null ? JSON.parse(existedFavRecipe) : [];
        setRecipeArray(data);
    }

    return (
 
            <FavRecipesContainer>           
                {recipeArray.map( e => (
                    <>
                        <FavRecipeImage src ={e.image} />
                        <FavRecipeTitle>{e.title}</FavRecipeTitle>
                    </>
                ))}
            </FavRecipesContainer>

    )
}
```

The problem is I want the function of  `refreshData` to get triggered automatically everytime the data in the array changes because i will create a delete button that can delete the favorite recipes. I am thinking of using useEffect() but I dont know how to do it. Is there any suggestion to solve this? Would appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean by data in the array ? do you want to listen to the local storage and get your function triggered at that point ?

Comment: you should try https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: @KavinduVIndika yes, exactly like that if possible. Actually, I just want to retrieve the latest recipes array data after user delete some recipe and display it to the users automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the function of `refreshData` to get triggered automatically everytime the data in the array changes because i will create a delete button that can delete the favorite recipes..

The problem is that there is no event that fires when local storage is changed by other code in the same window (the `storage` event only fires when storage is changed in **other** windows).

There are dodgy solutions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974084/listen-for-changes-with-localstorage-on-the-same-window), but really just make sure that your deletion code calls `refreshData` as part of its logic. Or actually, you don't even need `refreshData`, you could maintain the array locally in the component and just echo it to local storage:

```
const FavRecipes = () => {
    const [recipeArray, setRecipeArray] = useState([]);

    // Initial data load
    useEffect(() => {
        const existedFavRecipe = localStorage.getItem("FavRecipes");
        const data = existedFavRecipe !== null ? JSON.parse(existedFavRecipe) : [];
        setRecipeArray(data);
    }, []);

    // Deletion
    const deleteRecipe = (recipe) => {
        setRecipeArray(recipes => {
            recipes = recipes.filter(r => r !== recipe);
            localStorage.setItem("FavRecipes", JSON.stringify(recipes));
            return recipes;
        });
    };

    return (
            <FavRecipesContainer>           
                {recipeArray.map( recipe => (
                    <>
                        <FavRecipeImage src ={recipe.image} />
                        <FavRecipeTitle>{recipe.title}</FavRecipeTitle>
                        <button onClick={() => deleteRecipe(recipe)}>X</button>
                    </>
                ))}
            </FavRecipesContainer>
    );
};
```

If you also want to listen for changes in other windows (users do that):

```
const FavRecipesKey = "FavRecipes";
const FavRecipes = () => {
    const [recipeArray, setRecipeArray] = useState([]);

    // Initial data load and watch for changes in other windows
    useEffect(() => {
        function refreshData() {
            const existedFavRecipe = localStorage.getItem(FavRecipesKey);
            const data = existedFavRecipe !== null ? JSON.parse(existedFavRecipe) : [];
            setRecipeArray(data);
        }
        function storageEventHandler({key}) {
            if (key === FavRecipesKey) {
                refreshData();
            }
        }
        refreshData();
        window.addEventListener("storage", storageEventHandler);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("storage", storageEventHandler);
        };
    }, []);

    // Deletion
    const deleteRecipe = (recipe) => {
        setRecipeArray(recipes => {
            recipes = recipes.filter(r => r !== recipe);
            localStorage.setItem(FavRecipesKey, JSON.stringify(recipes));
            return recipes;
        });
    };

    return (
            <FavRecipesContainer>           
                {recipeArray.map( recipe => (
                    <>
                        <FavRecipeImage src ={recipe.image} />
                        <FavRecipeTitle>{recipe.title}</FavRecipeTitle>
                        <button onClick={() => deleteRecipe(recipe)}>X</button>
                    </>
                ))}
            </FavRecipesContainer>
    );
};
```

Comment: Crowder what is `recipe` and `recipes` in the `deleteRecipe` funtion ? i am quite confused

Comment: @Woppy - `recipe` is the recipe (array entry) being deleted. You can see that I'm passing that to `deleteRecipe` in `() => deleteRecipe(recipe)` where `recipe` is the parameter of the `map` callback.

Comment: @Crowder Got it! This method works and easy to understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one. The closest one in React camp is `useMutableSource`. https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/main/text/0147-use-mutable-source.md

However `useMutableSource` is a bit too advanced. So maybe we should think of the problem in another way. For instance, if you can know the time or component who invokes `localStorage.setItem`, then you can turn it in a context.

##### Define a context

Create a file that you can share to other components.

```
  const RecipeContext = React.createContext()
  export default RecipeContext
```

##### Import it to set it

When you want to set the content, import the context and write it via `current`.

```
  import RecipeContext from './RecipeContext'
  const AComponent = () => {
    const recipe = React.useContext(RecipeContext)
    recipe.current = recipeArray
  }
```

##### Import it to read it

When you want to read out the current value, import the context and read it via `current`.

```
  import RecipeContext from './RecipeContext'
  const BComponent = () => {
    const recipe = React.useContext(RecipeContext)
    const onClick = () => {
      console.log(recipe.current)
    }
  }
```

You should be able to use `RecipeContext` as a "global" variable similar to `localStorage`. Even better if you have any default value, you can set it at the time you create it.

```
  const RecipeContext = React.createContext(defaultRecipeArray)
```

You don't even need a provider `<RecipeContext.Provider />`, because you are using it as a "global" context, a very special usage.

Comment: How would they implement the deletion they talk about? `useContext` is only for *reading* context.

Comment: To delete, just do `recipe.current = null`, you are managing the storage directly, `useContext` is to read the context, but the context itself is writable via `current` property.

Comment: That won't make anything re-render, though, will it?

Comment: it can, if you have a top provider, `RecipeContext.Provider value="" />`. I  thought you don't need it, but yes if you want render, use provider.