# Listen localStorage in react(useEffect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using some third-party libraries in react. That will make some local storage change on the page. I tried to listen to that local storage change using javascript storage event and give localStorage.getItem('test') as the dependency of useEffect. But it is not listening to the localStorage change.

Here is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('test')));
  })
},[])
```

How to listen the localStorage event in react.

Comment: What is `window.storage`? Did you mean `window.addEventListener`?

Comment: *Note: This won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made. Pages on other domains can't access the same storage objects.* [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event)

Comment: Yes @Konrad.  It is window. addEventListener

Comment: Localstorage is on the same page only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listen for changes with localStorage on the same window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974084/listen-for-changes-with-localstorage-on-the-same-window)

Comment: This does not solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer [Listen for changes with localStorage on the same window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974084/listen-for-changes-with-localstorage-on-the-same-window)

React version:

Add this code before the other script add anything to local storage

```
const originalSetItem = localStorage.setItem;

localStorage.setItem = function (key, value) {
  const event = new Event("itemInserted");

  event.value = value; // Optional..
  event.key = key; // Optional..

  document.dispatchEvent(event);

  originalSetItem.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

In your component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const localStorageSetHandler = function (e) {
    alert('localStorage.set("' + e.key + '", "' + e.value + '") was called');
  };

  document.addEventListener("itemInserted", localStorageSetHandler, false);

  // remember to remove the listener
  return () =>
    document.removeEventListener("itemInserted", localStorageSetHandler);
}, []);
```

[image: See the example on codesandbox]

Comment: it is not working with mozilla

Answer (score -1):

You can this way!

```js
useEffect(() => {
  function checkLocalData() {
    const item = localStorage.getItem('test')

    if (item) {
      checkLocalData(item)
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('storage', checkLocalData)

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('storage', checkLocalData)
  }
}, [])
```